# Setting www in PowerDNS domain template to always CNAME to self

Tags: powerdns, templates

I found a pretty old answer from 2014 explaining that domain names in PowerDNS has to be fully qualified, thus CNAME cannot refer to self (@), and enhancements in this regard may have been implemented later, but creating a PowerDNS domain template, if referring to self is not possible using CNAME @, how do one set the domain template to always default a record (like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) to self (example.com)? Isn't that impossible?

Comment: Hi welcome to the site.
Which frontend are you using? Possibilities for entry of data depend heavily on the frontend that is used.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the PowerDNS-Admin at https://github.com/PowerDNS-Admin/PowerDNS-Admin.